# How to not to expose some variables from script setup to the template?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-script-setup

As it mentions [here](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#basic-syntax) all the top level bindinigs introduced in script setup are exposed to template.

Question: How to exclude some of them? Something like private vairables which are only available inside script setup but not then passed to template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do that with script setup. For advanced use cases use a setup function, where you can choose what to expose:

https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using `defineExpose` to define only what you want to expose?

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const a = 1
const b = ref(2)

defineExpose({
  a,
  b
})
</script>
```

ref. https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose

Comment: Here, OP wants to NOT expose, so it's actually the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide things on the client-side, you'll need a server (SSR with Nuxt for example) or a middleware of some sort (backend proxy, serverless function, etc...).

Here are two answers related to this question:

- [How to make a private call when using SSR Nuxt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67688915/how-to-make-a-private-call-when-using-ssr-nuxt/67689121#67689121)
- [CORS error and secret keys in network tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404032/cors-error-and-secret-keys-in-network-tab/72406663#72406663)

---

If by private, you mean OOP's private variables, then it's another subject: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-private-class-fields/#privateclassfields

If you want to only not expose the variables, then you'll need to use regular `setup()` into a `script()` and return only some of them. I don't think that there is a `hide()` function of some sort in Vue3.