# How to hide code from client side in vue/nuxt, using Server Side Rendering?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to do some processing on the server side, which I do not want to be viewable on the client side.

I have successfully tried using either `fetch` or `asyncData` to populate the state, but I do not want the process followed to be available on the browser.

For example:

```html
<template>
  // ...
</template>

<script>
import ...

export default {
  layout: 'layout1',

  name: 'Name',

  components: { ... },

  data: () => ({ ... }),

  computed: { ... },

  async asyncData({ store }) {

    const news = await axios.get(
      'https://newsurl.xml'
    ).then(feed =>
         // parse the feed and do some very secret stuff with it
         // including sha256 with a salt encryption
    )
    store.commit('news/ASSIGN_NEWS', news)
  }
}
</script>
```

I want the code in `asyncData` (or in `fetch`) not to be visible on the client side.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: maybe you can always fetch the data in `nuxtServerInit()`

Comment: @DengSihan that is very interesting, thanks, I will check it out. This is run as an action in store files, right? I'm on it

Answer (score 2):

There are several questions like this one already, one of which I've [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69575243/8816585) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67689121/8816585).

The TLDR being that if you want to make something on server only, you probably don't even want it part of a `.vue` file from the beginning. Using a backend proxy could also be useful (as stated above), especially if you could benefit from caching or reduce bandwidth overall.

Comment: So, basically, nuxtServerInit or a proxy?

Comment: @RubyRacer some more options overall. Depends of your use-case, what you want to achieve/prefer.

Comment: Not many things achieved so far. `nuxtServerInit` has to run globally, so I tried with a middleware. I'll do some reading and try stuff later on.

Comment: @RubyRacer yeah, it runs in Vuex but that should not be an issue per-se.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [onServerPrefetch](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#serverprefetch) hook.

```js
onServerPrefetch(async () => {
  const news = await axios.get(
  'https://newsurl.xml'
).then(feed =>
     // parse the feed and do some very secret stuff with it
     // including sha256 with a salt encryption
)
  this.$store.commit('news/ASSIGN_NEWS', news)
})
```

Comment: Never heard about that one before! So, it's baked-in into Vue3 compiler somehow? Or it assumes that we are using Nuxt?

Comment: This assumes we are using the options API from Vue 3. Unfortunately, it is not applicable.

Comment: You can use this hook on Nuxt project as well It will work

Comment: Even with Nuxt2?

Comment: Well as far as I know this hook available in Vue3 and Nuxt2 uses Vue2

Comment: Yep, this is exactly the point (OP using Nuxt2 here).